# How to get custom number buttons to show on correct input field react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Having a hard time seeing how I could accomplish this. I created some custom number buttons from 0-9 that users can click on instead of using the keyboard. The problem I'm having is I have multiple dynamically created input fields depending on JSON Data so let's say there are 10 dynamically created input fields and a user starts with question one and the user then uses the custom number buttons I created and clicks numbers "145" to answer question one, but what happens is then all 10 inputs have the same number "145" not the problem the user was trying to solve. I'm using the context API to then save the values typed in on a function called getButtonValue that I then call to the parent component and save the values in a state array, so I know that my problem is that all the inputs share the same state array but how could I make sure the correct input the user clicks on is only receiving those values.

Thanks in advance.

My Custom Number Button Component:

```
import { FormContext } from "../../lib/FormContext";

function ActivityBar() {
  const { getButtonValue } = useContext(FormContext);

  return (
    <div className={`${activity.activity__workSheet__numberButton}`}>
      <button value={0} onFocus={(e) => getButtonValue(e)}>
        <img
          className={`${activity.activity__workSheet__img0}`}
          src={"/assets/activityNumber-btn.png"}
          alt="activity number button"
        />
    .... more code
```

Parent Component:

const [numberButtonClicked, setNumberButtonClicked] = useState([]);

const getButtonValue = (e) => {

```
setNumberButtonClicked((prevButtonClicked) => [
  ...prevButtonClicked,
  e?.target?.attributes[0].value
]);
```

};

```
  return (
    <Carousel>
       <div ref={imageRef} style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          {Object.entries(elements).map((element, i) => {
             const { fields } = element[1];

              if (fields) {
                return (
                  <Element
                    key={i}
                    field={fields[0]}
                    id={i}
                    useReff={`answer${i}`}
                    currentValue={
                      numberButtonClicked === "" ? null : numberButtonClicked.join("")
                    }
                  />
                );
              } else {
               return;
             }
           })}
        </div>
     </Carousel>
```

Comment: One problem you'll need to solve is:  When the user clicks on a number button, how do you know which input field they intended the number to go into?  A problem you have with your code is that each of the `<Element>` things you are creating are set to the same currentValue.

Comment: Correct! yes, that's what i'm trying to figure out is how could i differentiate the different inputs with the currentValue.

Comment: Try using a separate variable for every input field, instead of the same value for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Got a good working version figured out for this scenario, what I did was.

I have a `onFocus` method on my input tags that then takes in the event and calls a `handleChange(e)` function. Within that function I then save the `currentInputId` in a variable by using `e?.target?.attributes[0]?.value` and the previous `InputId` in a state variable and just check if the previous `InputId` is equal to the `currentId` user just focused on. If so then we'll add the next number user clicks into the same field, else if `previousInputId !== currentInputId` then make my user value state array empty, `setNumberButtonClicked([])`.